# Update credit card in Stripe

Tags: laravel

I tried some solutions but I couldn't create a correct form to update the credit card.
I have created a special page to manage the credit card update.

**Also, I would like to understand when for an automatic subscription renewal you have a credit card that has expired or otherwise "fails", what happens? Does the subscription continue making X attempts?**

Right now, my code is as follows:

Controller

```
    public function setupPayment(){
            return view('update-card', [
                'intent' => Auth::user()->createSetupIntent()
            ]);
        }
```

```
        public function updateExistingCreditCard(Request $request){
            
            $key = \config('services.stripe.secret');
            $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient($key);
            
            $this->validate($request, [
                'address' => 'nullable',
                'name' => 'nullable'
            ]);
            
            $user = Cashier::findBillable(Auth::user()->stripe_id);
            //$user = Auth::user()->asStripeCustomer();
    
            if($user->hasDefaultPaymentMethod()){
                
                $stripe->customers->updateSource(
                    $user->stripe_id,
                    $user->id,
                    ['name' => 'Jenny Rosen']
                );
                
                return redirect()->back()->with('success','Update.');
                
            }
            
            return redirect()->back()->with('danger','Error.');
            
        }
```

HTML

```
<form id="payment-form" action="{{ route('update.new.credit.card') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-6">

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    {{ __('Update Card') }}
                </div>

                <div class="card-body">

                    <input id="card-holder-name" type="text">

                    <!-- Stripe Elements Placeholder -->
                    <div id="card-element"></div>

                    <button id="card-button" data-secret="{{ $intent->client_secret }}">
                        Update Payment Method
                    </button>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
</form>
```

```
    const stripe = Stripe('{{ config('cashier.key') }}');

    const elements = stripe.elements();
    const cardElement = elements.create('card');

    cardElement.mount('#card-element');
    
    const cardHolderName = document.getElementById('card-holder-name');
    const cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
    const clientSecret = cardButton.dataset.secret;

    cardButton.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
        const { setupIntent, error } = await stripe.confirmCardSetup(
            clientSecret, {
                payment_method: {
                    card: cardElement,
                    billing_details: { 
                        name: cardHolderName.value 
                    }
                }
            }
        );

        if (error) {
            document.getElementById('card-button').disabled = false
        } else {
            let token = document.createElement('input')
            
            token.setAttribute('type', 'hidden')
            token.setAttribute('name', 'token')
            token.setAttribute('value', setupIntent.payment_method)

            form.appendChild(token)

            form.submit();
        }
    });
```

---

UPDATE

In this new code, by inserting the metadata fields, they are correctly updated, so I guess the code is right. I am probably wrong with the parameters passed to update the card and make it default to the customer.

```
$stripeCustomer = Auth::user()->asStripeCustomer();
        $paymentMethod = $stripe->customers->retrieve($stripeCustomer->id)->invoice_settings->default_payment_method;

        if(Auth::user()->hasDefaultPaymentMethod()){
            
            $stripe->customers->update($stripeCustomer->id, [
                ['invoice_settings' => ['default_payment_method' => $paymentMethod]]
            ]);
            
            return redirect()->back()->with('success','Update.');
            
        }
```